# How do I solve this error, so that I may successfully launch Python through my command prompt?

Tags: python, json, path, command-prompt, python-3.11

OK, so I'm a TOTAL newbie to Python, & I hope this is the only time I will ever have to use it!  But in any case, this is my dilemma...

To begin, I wish to execute the Python 3.11 program in CMD Prompt so that I may run my .py file "the-great-suspender-restore-urls", which will help to, well, restore the broken Great Suspender links in my saved Chrome session (named tabs.json) by changing them all back to their actual URLs.  The commands I need to run this Python script are as follows:

**C:\Users>cd Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4**

**C:\Users\User\Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4>python thegreatsuspender.py**

**restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json**

As I have been directed by another Python user, I have both the G.S.R.U. Python script & the Tabs JSON file that needs fixing in the same folder (which is highlighted in blue in the picture below).  After that, I changed the Path user variable by putting the link to the aforementioned folder as its value.  I also changed the Path system variable value to the folder where my Python program is (highlighted in faint gray).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIXQP.png)

So, it seems like everything should work out perfectly from this point on, right? WRONG!  For as soon as I told CMD Prompt to do the second of the three commands listed above, I got this instead:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4>python thegreatsuspender.py
**usage: thegreatsuspender.py [-h] --in-file IN_FILE --out-file OUT_FILE [--session-name-suffix SESSION_NAME_SUFFIX]
[--extension-id EXTENSION_ID] [--verbose]
thegreatsuspender.py: error: the following arguments are required: --in-file, --out-file

C:\Users\User\Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4>restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json
'restore-the-great-suspender-urls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

So, how am I supposed to overcome THIS hurdle? All I wanna do is just run this freaking Python script to restore my broken Great Suspender URLS:

**restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json**

I've been trying to accomplish this task for almost 2 weeks, & I'm really getting frustrated & desperate. :-(

Comment: try saying `python restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json` and if that does not work, `python restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=./tabs.json --out-file=./tabs-restored.json`

Comment: @cyberghost
I tried both, & I got this message instead.

**C:\Users\User\Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4> python restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=./tabs.json --out-file=./tabs-restored.json
python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4\\restore-the-great-suspender-urls': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

But how can that be? I set up the right paths to Python, my script, & everything!  Why can't it find the file &/or directory? :-(

Comment: shame on me. looking at in now, it seems that the `restore-the-great-suspender-urls` file, should obviously have a `.py` extension. try adding that and see what happens. like this: `python restore-the-great-suspender-urls.py --in-file=./tabs.json --out-file=./tabs-restored.json`

Comment: @cyberghost
**(sighs)** Alas, adding the .py extension did not work, either.  My latest attempt was met with this error message:

**C:\Users\User\Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4>python restore-the-great-suspender-urls.py --in-file=./tabs.json --out-file=./tabs-restored.json
python: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4\\restore-the-great-suspender-urls.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

What on Earth should to do now? :-( And can anyone else please lend their assistance, if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: that is a true b*****d. can you `type` the file? like `type restore-the-great-suspender-urls.py`? what output does that give you?

Comment: @cyberghost

"The system cannot find the file specified." :-(

**(sighs in frustration)** OK, just so we're on the up & up:
I linked environmental variable paths to the respective locations of my Python program & the Python script I want to run to restore my broken Great Suspender URLs (which are in a JSON tabs list in the latter folder).  I can get Python itself to be recognized & used by Command Prompt, but any commands involving my Great Suspender Restore URLs are totally bust.  What else could I be doing wrong, or is there something right that I'm not doing?

Comment: if it's saying `the system cannot find the file specified` , that is obviously not a python issue, that is an issue with your path, and seeing in you above post that you navigated to the correct directory, most likely the issue is with your file name. maybe the file is corrupt or, (bear with me please!) the filename is incorrect, cause that could very easily be where your problem is. i couldn't start to tell you how many times i would try to troubleshoot an issue with files only to find out i spelled their names incorrectly.

Comment: Maybe, we need some other people who can help us help me figure this out. **(giggles)**

Comment: @cyberghost

You might be on to something!  I'll go look into it straight away!

Comment: @cyberghost

No, the file & script names are all spelled perfectly. :-( So, it seems that we must rule that out, as well.  Darn it...What else can be done?

Comment: this is an odd one, i'll admit. but we can try something else. first navigate to the directory via cmd and run `dir`, and post the output

Comment: @cyberghost

Did it! ^_^ This is the output I got (I'll have to post it in parts, due to character limit):

**Directory of C:\Users\User\Desktop\the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4

05/20/2023  10:28 AM    <DIR>          .   /////   05/20/2023  10:28 AM    <DIR>          ..   /////   02/09/2021  06:22 PM               833 CHANGELOG.rst   /////   02/04/2021  05:04 PM             1,073 LICENSE   /////   02/04/2021  07:26 PM               107 MANIFEST.in 
  /////   02/09/2021  06:31 PM             6,306 PKG-INFO**

Comment: **02/09/2021  06:26 PM             4,082 README.rst   /////   02/09/2021  06:31 PM                53 setup.cfg   /////   02/09/2021  06:21 PM             1,810 setup.py   /////   04/07/2023  01:46 PM         4,048,672 tabs.json   /////   02/09/2021  06:31 PM            40,960 the-great-suspender-restore-urls-0.4.tar   /////   02/09/2021  06:21 PM             5,978 thegreatsuspender.py   /////   05/20/2023  10:28 AM    <DIR>          the_great_suspender_restore_urls.egg-info**

Comment: uh... i don't see the file `restore-the-great-suspender-urls` your were talking about. maybe the correct one is `thegreatsuspender.py`. or it might be in the `tar` archive. have you extracted the contents of that?

Comment: oh, one more thing, did you use `pip` to install it?

Comment: To put it as succinctly as possible, & as you see by the pictures in link(https://ibb.co/album/HB2xRp): **(1)** Python is indeed installed, but not PIP.  Efforts to install &/or update PIP in Command Prompt failed. _(Oh, BTW, the pictures in the album might actually be in the order opposite from how I've listed them.)_

Comment: **(2)** And since I actually never had PIP installed this whole time, no wonder I could never run thegreatsuspender.py! (And this revelation also leads me to believe that I didn't even actually unpack & install the Great-Suspender-Restore-URLs Python package to begin with!) ^

Comment: **(3)** Hopefully, if I can do that, I can finally run the GSRU Python Script & restore all of my broken Great Suspender links! ^_^ So....how do I do all that?

Comment: ^ **(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, & 9)** Or, alternatively, my attempts to install & unpack the Great Suspender Restore URLs package through a non-PIP program may have totally confused the computer, Command Prompt, &/or Python.  If that turns out to be the case, then how should I fix it?

Comment: And one more thing: If I only follow the scriptmaker's instructions of _"pip install the-great-suspender-restore-urls"_ & _"restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json"_, then how will my Python script be able to run if I don't tell them the location?

Comment: that clears up a lot of things. :) once you installed it via pip, just navigate to the directory and run the command like you tried to from the start `restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json` cause the installation will add it to path if it needs to. just go on youtube for advice for fixing the pip installation, and once its installed run 'pip install the-great-suspender-restore-urls` to install it. then the command should work and you can finally :) fix your broken urls.

Comment: @cyberghost I checked to see if PIP was installed, & the G.R.S.U. Python package was also installed.  Both were positive! ^_^ But, then, when I tried to run the final code, I got this result: https://i.ibb.co/N7W9hX2/One-Last-Obstacle.png .  Just ONE LAST OBSTACLE to overcome! DX But how to do it?

Comment: thankfully, thats an easy one, (or it seems at least). the problem is, that your running the command one at a time instead of as a part of the application. so just running `--in-file` for instance, has no effect cause the system knows nothing about a command named `--in-file`  what you have to do for example, is this `restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file`. now run the following command, all in one line, in the directory where your tabs files are: `restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json` make sure you have it all in one line though!!!

Comment: I did as you said...&, now, there's this problem: https://i.ibb.co/0GVK6zM/OK-Just-One-More-Hurdle-To-Jump.png .  So close, & yet so far! *(sighs)* Now what?

Comment: i'm not saying this will fix the issue, but try creating a `tabs-restored.json` file. by rights you should not have to do this, but it might help in this case. i'll do some research on that error and get back to you.

Comment: @cyberghost I don't think that'll work; besides, the "tabs-restored" JSON file is supposed to be the "tabs" file with the fixed URLs.  What did you find out?

Comment: the application threw this error, because basically, it's trying to parse the data in a way that it can't. if you want to fix this, you can either convert the file, or edit the python code. i would recommend trying to converting the file first. to do this easily, you'll need to download and install notepad++. then open the tabs file with notepad++, and check it says `UTF-8-BOM` in the bottom right hand corner.

Comment: It does say UTF-8-BOM.  So what do I do now?

Comment: now go to the encoding menu, and convert to utf-8 encoding WITHOUT the BOM, and save the file. then open it again to ensure that the BOM is in fact removed.

Comment: then, when you have in fact removed the BOM,  you can copy it into your tabs folder, and try restoring your urls again. Good Luck!

Comment: I converted the file with Notepad++! ^_^ Now, I'm going to try again...& I really hope it works this time! (crosses fingers)

Comment: I've almost got it, I'VE ALMOST GOT IT!!! ^_^ I have all of the right input codes I need! https://ibb.co/5RfgqLw And all I need to do now is fix this last freaking problem! :D https://ibb.co/fqV6P9j How do I do it? ^_^

Comment: just simply run this: `restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json` all in one line, from the tabs directory. ignore whatever is in the text file, you most likely don't need any of those options.

Comment: Ehhh, @cyberghost, it appears that I actually do need all that info I wrote down in the text document. https://i.ibb.co/874XW4m/It-Appears-We-Have-Yet-Another-Problem.png How, then, should I enter the information into Command Prompt?

Comment: bro, just enter the command like i told you in my last comment. all the other params are optional.

Comment: Sis, actually. ^^;; But if they're optional, I might as well put them in, lest I get the error message again. :-) But how do you properly format the text for these options in Command Prompt? (For instance, do you need brackets, will CMD allow the use of tab spacing, etc.)

Comment: sorry. :) but when a param is optional, especially in this case, it's really a better idea to just pretend it's not there, and if you do in fact need it, the program will most likely let you know when you try to run it. on how to format it, see next comment.

Comment: `C:\Users\user>restore-the-great-suspender-urls --in-file=tabs.json --out-file=tabs-restored.json` it should be all in one line. do NOT put line breaks in there! also remember that you'll have to first navigate to your tabs dir.

Comment: Nope.  Failed again... :-( https://i.ibb.co/M2GNndG/So-Close-Yet-So-Far.png

Comment: Maybe, we need to find other people who can answer & help out. :-) To whom should we turn, & where shall we find them? (Preferably on StackOverflow!)

Comment: after looking at the source code and the error traceback, it seems that your infile is at fault cause the code seems fine to me. it may be something you did while extracting the urls, i really don't know.

Comment: have you looked at other ways to restore the urls?